# Is a flex-wrap/inline-block style of item wrapping supported by React Virtualized?

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I currently have a list of items, like `<ul><li/><li/>...</ul>`, each styled with `display: inline-block`.  The items aren't a fixed height or width, though I could probably make them fixed, and each contains a thumbnail image and sometimes text.

The list responsively wraps as the window width changes, with no horizontal scrollbar.  For example, the list might start out with 3 items, which all fit horizontally on a row within the window:

```
| 1 2 3     |
```

Then some more items are added, and the items start wrapping to a second line:

```
| 1 2 3 4 5 |
| 6 7 8     |
```

Then if the window width changes, the items will re-wrap:

```
| 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 |
| 8             |
```

When there are thousands of items, performance can definitely suffer, so I wanted to see if there was a way to virtualize the list.  From my reading of the docs, it doesn't seem like this is currently supported by the React Virtualized library, but I wanted to check.  The `Collection` component seems like it might be close, but I don't think it expects to dynamically change width or height as the window is resized.

If this sort of item wrapping is possible, are there any example implementations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> From my reading of the docs, it doesn't seem like this is currently supported by the React Virtualized library

I'd love to know which part of the docs gave you this impression. Your use case sounds like one react-virtualized is well equipped to handle. :)

> The `Collection` component seems like it might be close

`Collection` is intended for something else. Maybe [these slides from a recent conference talk I gave](https://bvaughn.github.io/connect-tech-2016/#/15/1) could clarify that a bit. Basically, `Collection` is for non-linear data (eg Gantt charts, Pinterest layouts, etc). It's more flexible but that comes at a performance cost. Your use case sounds perfect for `List`. :)

## Updated Answer

You can use `List` and `AutoSizer` to accomplish this. You'll just need to calculate the number of rows using the available width and your item heights. Not too complicated. :)

[Here is an example Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/zjCwNeRZ7XtmFp1PDBsc/) and here is the source:

```
const { AutoSizer, List } = ReactVirtualized

const ITEMS_COUNT = 100
const ITEM_SIZE = 100

// Render your list
ReactDOM.render(
  <AutoSizer>
    {({ height, width }) => {
      const itemsPerRow = Math.floor(width / ITEM_SIZE);
      const rowCount = Math.ceil(ITEMS_COUNT / itemsPerRow);

      return (
        <List
          className='List'
          width={width}
          height={height}
          rowCount={rowCount}
          rowHeight={ITEM_SIZE}
          rowRenderer={
            ({ index, key, style }) => {
              const items = [];
              const convertedIndex = index * itemsPerRow;

              for (let i = convertedIndex; i < convertedIndex + itemsPerRow; i++) {
                items.push(
                  <div
                    className='Item'
                    key={i}
                  >
                    Item {i}
                  </div>
                )
              }

              return (
                <div
                  className='Row'
                  key={key}
                  style={style}
                >
                  {items}
                </div>
              )
            }
          }
        />
      )
    }}
  </AutoSizer>,
  document.getElementById('example')
)
```

## Initial Answer

Here is what I would do, more or less:

```
export default class Example extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    list: PropTypes.instanceOf(Immutable.List).isRequired
  }

  constructor (props, context) {
    super(props, context)

    this._rowRenderer = this._rowRenderer.bind(this)
    this._rowRendererAdapter = this._rowRendererAdapter.bind(this)
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate (nextProps, nextState) {
    return shallowCompare(this, nextProps, nextState)
  }

  render () {
    const { list } = this.props

    return (
      <AutoSizer>
        {({ height, width }) => (
          <CellMeasurer
            cellRenderer={this._rowRendererAdapter}
            columnCount={1}
            rowCount={list.size}
            width={width}
          >
            {({ getRowHeight }) => (
              <List
                height={height}
                rowCount={list.size}
                rowHeight={getRowHeight}
                rowRenderer={this._rowRenderer}
                width={width}
              />
            )}
          </CellMeasurer>
        )}
      </AutoSizer>
    )
  }

  _getDatum (index) {
    const { list } = this.props

    return list.get(index % list.size)
  }

  _rowRenderer ({ index, key, style }) {
    const datum = this._getDatum(index)

    return (
      <div
        key={key}
        style={style}
      >
        {datum.name /* Or whatever */}
      </div>
    )
  }

  _rowRendererAdapter ({ rowIndex, ...rest }) {
    return this._rowRenderer({
      index: rowIndex,
      ...rest
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I updated my question with some ASCII art to try to better explain what I'm trying to do. The `rowCount={list.size}` makes me think your solution creates a list with just one item per row. What I'm trying to do is show an arbitrary number of items per row, depending on the width of the window.

Comment: Oh! I see. :)

Here is a Plunker I created showing how to do this: https://embed.plnkr.co/zjCwNeRZ7XtmFp1PDBsc/

I will update my initial answer.

Comment: Thanks, that example is great! I there's a bug in the example in that if there are fewer than `itemsPerRow` cells left, it'll draw a full row anyway. But that seems fixable. For the record, I think it was seeing only one-item-per-fixed-width-row examples in the <List> documentation that made think it wouldn't be a good fit for this use case.